# Should I reset a users session after the user is logged in?

Tags: servlets

Which one should I use on creating a new session to the user after him has been logged in on the system

```
req.getSession().setAttribute(“user”, user);
```

or

```
req.getSession().invalidate();
req.getSession(true).setAttribute(“user”, user);
```

**EDIT**

The first one associates the user with the session given by the server on the first request and the second one creates a brand new one

Comment: How does the user login?

Comment: getSession(true) isn't different from getSession() if you are using HttpServletRequest. You would need to invalidate the current session first before getting a new session.

Comment: So, it that better using 1) req.getSession().setAttribute(“user”, user);
or 2) req.getSession().invalidate() and then req.getSession(true).setAttribute(“user”, user);?